# TFS eclipse plugin fails to check in changes that span Multiple Folders within a project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, tfs, checkin

I've found that you can't check in changes using that eclipse TFS plugin that span multiple folders within a project.

The only way I can get around this is to check in the changes from one folder at a time!

Surely this is a bug or a setting in eclipse I've missed. In either case its making checking in code very tedious. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Patrick Many thanks for your response. I think I've gotten to the bottom of it. So if you Add a file to your project, rename it and then delete it. And then try to make a checkin. The TFS plugin on Eclipse will fail to submit the changes until you right click on the deleted file and Undo it.

I'm thinking TFS is acting correctly because it should allow the user to submit a deleted file into TFS. However the Eclipse plugin doesn't give the user any feedback as to why the checkin has failed. It just fails silently.

If you've got a lot of files to checkin as part of your checkin then it can easily become confusing as to why the checkin fails.

Answer (score 0):

Check in multiple folders definitely be supported by TFS eclipse plugin. Test pass on my enviroment through [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx) without any additional settings.

You can specify which file changes you want to check in. On the
**Pending Changes** page, select one or more changes in the Excluded Changes section. Choose Include from the shortcut menu. You can also
scope your check-in as you work in other areas of Eclipse:

**Way1:** In Package Explorer or Project Explorer, select one of the following:

◦One or more of the code projects

◦One or more folders

◦One or more files

After you select the items, open their shortcut menu, and choose Team, Check In Pending Changes.

[image]

**Way2:** In Source Control Explorer, select one or more items with pending changes or one or more folders that contain items with pending changes. (Items with pending changes are indicated by this symbol: √ ). Open the shortcut menu of the selected items, and choose Check In.

More info of it from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155785(v=vs.120).aspx